# MVC User Sortable List

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list partial view in MVC5, and would like a nice clean way for the users to sort the list. The objects have a SortOrder field, so I would like that updated based on how the user sorts them.

If it's a matter of Up/Down buttons, okay, but draggable would be nice.

Comment: show what have you tried so far

Comment: I was thinking about this, but the code was for MVC2, and seems a little out of date. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/01/01/drag-and-drop-sorting-for-our-aspnet-mvc-list-editor-in-one-line-of-code/

Comment: sortable is a jquery plugin so mvc version doesn't really matter.  it's pretty easy to use.  You still have to write your own javascript to handle the drop events and update the SortOrder yourself.